# Looping and output in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, google-apps-script

I am using 2 sheets, `rawData` and `processedData`.

`rawData` looks like this:

`Status` `Title`  `Options`
`Live`   `Title1` `Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4`
`Live`   `Title2` `Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, Option5`
`Live`   `Title3` `Option1, Option2, Option3`

`processedData` should look like this:

`Status`  `Title` `Options`
`Live`    `Title1` `Option1`
`empty`   `Title1` `Option2`
`empty`   `Title1` `Option3`
`empty`   `Title1` `Option4`
`Live`    `Title2` `Option1`
`empty`   `Title2` `Option2`
`empty`   `Title2` `Option3`
`empty`   `Title2` `Option4`
`empty`   `Title2` `Option5`
`Live`    `Title3` `Option1`
`empty`   `Title3` `Option2`
`empty`   `Title3` `Option3`

The `empty`is supposed to be empty, didn't know how to leave it blank to represent an empty cell.

I tried using this code, but I can't get the desired output with the loops.

```
function formatData() {

  // File
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Get rawData sheet
  var rawData = ss.getSheetByName('rawData');

  // Input data
  var data = rawData.getRange("A2:C").getValues(); // Gets titles and options in a single call to the sheet

  // Initialise an array that will hold the output
  var outputArray = [];

  // Name a variable to hold the data from each set of options
  var options;

  var status;

  // Start looping through the data
  for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {

    status = data[row][0];

    outputArray.push([status]);

    // Split the options into an array: "Option1, Option2, Option3" ---> [Option1, Option2, Option3]
    options = data[row][1].split(", ");

    // Loop through the array of split options and place each of them in a new row
    for (var element = 0; element < options.length; element++) {

      outputArray.push([data[row][0], // Place the title in a new row
                        options[element]]); // Place one option in the 2nd column of the row

    } // Options loop ends here

  } // Data loop ends here

  // Get processedData sheet
  var processedData = ss.getSheetByName('processedData');

  // Get last row in processedData sheet
  var lastRow = processedData.getLastRow();

  // Post the outputArray to the sheet in a single call
  processedData.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, outputArray.length, outputArray[0].length).setValues(outputArray);
}
```

I'm a total beginner in this language, sorry for asking a probably very basic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several modifications.

### Pattern 1:

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows. Please modify the for loop as follows.

```
for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
  status = data[row][0];
  var title = data[row][1]; // Added
//    outputArray.push([status]); // Removed
  options = data[row][2].split(", "); // Modified
  for (var element = 0; element < options.length; element++) {
    if (element == 0) { // Added and modified
      outputArray.push([status, title, options[element]]);
    } else {
      outputArray.push(["", title, options[element]]);
    }
  }
}
```

### Pattetn 2:

As another pattern, how about the following modification? When you use this, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
// Initialise an array that will hold the output
var outputArray = [];

// Name a variable to hold the data from each set of options
var options;

var status;

// Start looping through the data
for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {

  status = data[row][0];

  outputArray.push([status]);

  // Split the options into an array: "Option1, Option2, Option3" ---> [Option1, Option2, Option3]
  options = data[row][1].split(", ");

  // Loop through the array of split options and place each of them in a new row
  for (var element = 0; element < options.length; element++) {

    outputArray.push([data[row][0], // Place the title in a new row
                      options[element]]); // Place one option in the 2nd column of the row

  } // Options loop ends here

} // Data loop ends here
```

To:

```
var outputArray = data.reduce(function(ar1, e) {
  var h1 = e.splice(0, 1)[0];
  var h2 = e.splice(0, 1)[0];
  var options = e[0].split(", ");
  return ar1.concat(options.reduce(function(ar2, f, j) {
    if (f) ar2.push(j == 0 ? [h1, h2, f] : ["", h2, f]);
    return ar2;
  }, []));
}, []);
```

- The result is the same with the pattern 1.

### Note:

- In your script, it seems that the header of "Status, Title, Options" is not copied. How about this?

### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you - I was able to use your "Pattern 1" code to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @kamen1111 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.